# rate limit of github using node.js

Tags: node.js, github

I am writing an app using node.js which sends a request to github and fetches the html page of github project issues. when I send more request for 40th page I am getting 429 response for request. how can i overcome this RATE limit of github?

```js
function requestPage(pageNo){
 var changedUrl = url+"?page="+pageNo+"&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen";    //URL for requesting all the pages individually 
 request(changedUrl, function(error, response, html){    //requesting thee web page
  if(error){
   return error;
  }
  else{
   var $ = cheerio.load(html);

   if(pageNo == 40){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    fs.writeFile("page.html", html ,'utf8',function(err){
     if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
     }
     console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 
 
   }   
             //functions
  }
 });   
 }

for (var i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
 requestPage(i);
}
```

Comment: Whenever your request received a `429` response, you can use `setTimeout` and/or a queue to trigger your next request only once the 
wait delay is elapsed... Request header `X-RateLimit-Remaining` returned by github should let you know how long you need to wait.

Comment: I am new to this, Can you please tell me how to check "X-RateLimit-Remaining" in response

Comment: sure, but  you should share your code first: how do you connect to github's API?

Comment: request("github url", function(error, response, html){
  //Checking for the errors in the requested url
  if(error){
   return error;
  }else if(response.statusCode == 404){
    res.status(404).send("error");
  }else{
                  functions
               }


this is the code.

Comment: @SunilKumar Please [edit] your question to include the relevant piece of code. Comments are not suitable for it.

Comment: Have a look at `response.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining']` inside the request callback...

Comment: Also, please use Google. Searching for "github api limits" very quickly gave me this article: https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/

Comment: @mef Please check the above code

Answer (score 1):

#### using the right tool for the right job

First, please note that you should better use [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) instead of requesting the HTML pages. It should make your work easier, as you'll directly get the data you are interested in in JSON format, without having to parse HTML.
Issues API endpoints  are documented [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/).

You also should check whether github allows you to crawl their page, and make sure you don't overload their servers with your requests.

#### fixing your code

However, in case you want to continue the way you're doing, you arrange your code this way:

**handle rate limiting**

Inside `request` function callback, you should add a condition to check the response from github:

```
request(changedUrl, function(error, response, html){
    if(error){
        return error;
    }
    else{
        if (response.headers.status === '429 Too Many Requests') {
            setTimeout(function() {requestPage(pageNo)}, 54000000}) // retry in some delay (find out the appropriate timeout value)
        }
        else {
            ... //continue the processing
```

**behaving well**

Another change required in your code may avoid you from being rate-limited. It should also spare your CPU and github servers' too.

This is bad:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
    requestPage(i);
}
```

Reason: your are sending `noOfPages` requests to github quasi-simultaneously.

How to fix: use a recursive function instead of a `for` loop, and set a delay between the calls.

Fixed code:

```js
function requestPage(pageNo){
var changedUrl = url+"?page="+pageNo+"&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen";    //URL for requesting all the pages individually 
 
 request(changedUrl, function(error, response, html){    //requesting thee web page
  if(error){
   return error;
  }
  else{
   if (response.headers.status === '429 Too Many Requests') {
    // retry to request the same page after some delay
    setTimeout(function() {requestPage(pageNo)}, 54000000})
   }
   else {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    if(pageNo == 40){
     console.log(response.statusCode);
     fs.writeFile("page.html", html ,'utf8',function(err){
      if(err) {
       return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("The file was saved!");
     }); 

    if (i < noOfPages) {
     // request next page after a small delay
     setTimeout(function() {requestPage(pageNo+1)}, 15000})
    }
   }
  }
 });   
}

// request the first page immediately
requestPage(1);
```

I leave it up to you to cleanup the hard-coded `if(pageNo == 40){`, which probably should be `if(pageNo == noOfPages){` and could be arranged with the following if clause.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any other method other than recursvie? Because if pages are more it will take more time

Comment: To speed things up you may use a queue system, and introduce some parallelism. Caolan's [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) module will help you. But first, really, start using the API.

Comment: how to do authentication for github from node.js

Answer (score 0):

In ES7 with babel, just one page at a time:

```
import req from 'request-promise';

async function getPages(urls) {
  for (let url of urls) {
    let html = await req(url);
    console.log(html);   
 }
```